# Using java.util.Collections.synchronizedList with Scala's .asScala converter

Tags: java, scala

The JavaDoc of `java.util.Collections.synchronizedList` says the following

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it:
>
> ```
> List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
> ...
> synchronized (list) {
>   Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
>     while (i.hasNext())
>       foo(i.next());
> }
> ```
>
> Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic behavior.

Now i wonder what happens when I use the `.asScala` function from `scala.collection.JavaConverters` on it and `.map` over it.

Will the converter take care of the synchronizing during the iteration or do I still have to do it on my own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.asScala` function returns a `scala.collection.mutable.Buffer` which doesn't do anything about synchronizing.

```
scala> Collections.synchronizedList(new util.ArrayList[Int]())
res0: java.util.List[Int] = []

scala> res0.asScala
res1: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Int] = Buffer()
```

The answer to your question is, you have to take care of synchronization.